# C#- i want a method which create a list oop

Tags: c#, oop

This is my first question on this platform. You are some gods for me!
I have a small project where i learn how to see OOP in C#.
I have 4 clases( Shape,square,circle,triangle)
Square class have implemented 2 functions(Area and perimeter) and a method GetPrint which have those functions implemented. The other classes have implemented area and perimeter with the required formulas for each form.
Now i have to create another class ShapeFactory which have 2 interfaces( ReadData and PrintData).
I need a way to implement a function in the ReadData which store all the forms created in the console in a list and after i choose the option 4(Exit) to display the area and perimeter which was stored in that table.
For example:

```
            do
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose a form:");
            Console.WriteLine("1:Triangle");
            Console.WriteLine("2:Square");
            Console.WriteLine("3:Circle");
            Console.WriteLine("4:Exit");

            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);

            if (i == 1)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("l1:");
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("l2:");
                int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("l3:");
                int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Triangle t = new Triangle(n, m, q);
                t.GetPrint();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

I need all the informations which the user add in the console for this triangle to be stored in a Table with the ReadData interface and to be printed from that tabel with the PrintData interface. I tried to implement the PrintData to use the first idea GetPrint which display the area and perimeter in the console once IF statement is ended.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck? Surely you don't expect us to just write the code for you? (And if you do -- that's not what the site is for.)

Comment: no i am not asking for that. The thing is that i need to learn more about how to work with interfaces. I tried a lot of things in order to implement something on those interfaces, but it's now showing me any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite confused on what you want to happen..

Let's say square, circle and triangle inherits from shape..

```
 public class Circle : Shape
```

the on the main method of your program..

```
    List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
    do
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a form:");
        Console.WriteLine("1:Triangle");
        Console.WriteLine("2:Square");
        Console.WriteLine("3:Circle");
        Console.WriteLine("4:Exit");

        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);

        if (i == 1)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("l1:");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("l2:");
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("l3:");
            int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Triangle t = new Triangle(n, m, q);
            shapes.Add(t);
            t.GetPrint();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        // do the same for square and circle
        // shapes.Add(variable);
```

On the end of your application before it exits..

you can

```
foreach(var shape in shapes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}\nPerimeter: {1}\n", shape.Area, shape.Perimeter); 
}
```

Not sure if this is what you want...

Comment: I am still working on it,but I think you gave me a good idea. Thank you for your quick response. I will come back if i get a result.